# How to create Jira listener?

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I created a filter in Jira, which displays a list of issues. I am in process of writing a programm in Python, which could send me new issues from this filter. I suppose that I need something like Jira listener in order to get this issue in real time, but I'm not sure how.
I'll be thankful for any advice or documentation. Any other variants are fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a push mechanism for this. JIRA has a fairly comprehensive REST API that you can wrap easily with Python (as has already been done [here](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which may be all you need). You will need to poll in a loop though.

1. [Get the Filter](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/filter-getFilter) (note you must know the filter's id as you cannot search for a Filter by its name!!) (*)
2. [Call back to invoke the JQL](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/search) it contains
3. Process processing jira issue results.

(*) My ugly workaround for this was to have a "magic" issue whose body had a few control commands (poll-frequency etc) and manually linked to the Filters to watch. I then searched for issues with a certain tag and parsed out the links

Comment: I think I get the general idea on how to create a server, but I don't know how to make Jira send data.